# Deploy & Manage client/server application on multiple client servers

Tags: php, database, web-applications, deployment, client-server

We're currently developing a 'sort of' e-commerce platform for our customers that are using our POS system.

This mainly exists of:

- An Angular client-side
- A PHP API as back-end
- A MySQL database

Before I distribute the application to clients, I want to have a 'manageable' system for deploying and updating their platforms in case of code changes etc.

The initial setup would be:

- Create database
- Copy PHP files
- Run composer
- Run migrations
- Modify configuration file for database credentials, salts, domain,..
- Copy client side files

I was looking at Deployer for PHP, but I'm not sure how the whole database creation and config file modifications would work. I've originaly have the database creation in one of my migrations, but this would require a root db-user (or one with create permissions) and this user would need to be created as well.

The intial setup part could be done manually (it's not like it will be more than 5+ installations per week or so, but I would like to make it as simple as possible so that our support can do this instead of me every time)

The next part would be Updates.

I don't want to FTP to every server and apply changes. Updates can be both server side and client side. What would be the best way to do this:

- Have a central system with all versions and registered websites at our end and let the client server daily check for a new version. If there is a new version, download all files from our server and run the migrations.
- Push via deployer the new version to all clients. But this would overwrite or move the original config file with the DB credentials etc with the new version?

What if I need to add a new config setting? (application settings are stored in the database, but like the 'API' settings are within a config file.)

There will be a chance that all these client-servers will be distributed via our hosting provider, so we'll have access to all of them and they'll all be the same (for the configuration and such)

I've only written web applications used on one (server) location, so updating those were easy, for example via deploybot and such and the database setup was done manually, but now I'm stepping up my game and I want to make sure that I don't give myself more work than it should be.

Comment: Hi. Did you find an idea ?

Answer (score -1):

Here's our [case](https://www.codenetix.com/cases/so) on developing an e-commerce platform - maybe you'll find answers to your questions there.

Codenetix spezializes in custom development, mostly web apps, so if you need help - let us know.

Good luck with your project!